# Trying to run make menuconfig to manually configure the kernel, but gets an error

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I downloaded the linux operating system kernel source `4.15.1`
from the kernel website, installed the required packages:

```
kernel-package, libncurses5 and libncurses5-dev.
```

Unpacked the tar archive and navigated to the resulting directory.
I wanted to proceed to the kernel configuration, but when I enter the `make menuconfig`command,
I get the following error:

```
make: *** empty variable name. Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:460: scripts_basic] Error 2
```

I tried for a very long time to find a solution to this problem on the internet, reinstalling all packages, even looking at the contents of the Makefile kernel file, but nothing gave me any results.

Although after entering this command I was expecting an ncurses utility to open for manual kernel tuning, but only my version, like this:
[image: utility ncurses]

Comment: Are you sure there is no error message **above** the lines you show? Have you run `make menuconfig` **exactly**, without any options?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, yeah, I'm sure I did everything as required, as it turned out there were missing files in the kernel directory.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the error and run the utility by re-downloading the package with a different compression method.
For some reason, the `.xz` format I selected does not decompress correctly.
The error was that not all required kernel files were present.